# google spreadsheets automatically add price on form submission

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Forms for t-shirt orders, and I want to add "=M2" to the row's H cell, and "=MINUS(Hx,N2)" (where x is the row number) in the row's I cell for every shirt ordered. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try: 
`=arrayformula(MINUS(H2:H,N2))`
formula to put in row 2